# When Raiden is turned into a cyborg?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-series

I know that Raiden is turned into a cyborg at some point of MGS, but what I want to know is if this is shown in some point of the game or is just mentioned at some point? is there some actually playable scene or some cutscene that shows how Raiden gets turned into a cyborg?

Comment: This is incorrect, Raiden was turned into a cyborg before the events of MGS4.

Comment: @Ender Well sorry, when was he turned on so I can edit my question?

Comment: I have no idea, I just know that when MGS4 plot begins he's already the way he is.

Comment: @Ender Okey updated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After recusing Sunny he worked with EVA and her Paradise Lost Army however was captured by the Patriots where they experimented on him, while he was recused but the damage to his body was to severe so Dr Madmar made him into the Cyborg Ninja we see him as in MGS4, maybe also because of Raiden becoming more fascinated with Japaneses culture after using the HF Blade played a part in his appearance.

the Big Shell Incident was in 2009 and MGS4 was set in 2014, given that after Big Shell him and Rose continued to see each other and the whole thing about Jack's kid we can probably assume that he rescued Sunny in around 2010-2011, considering then distances Raiden would have had to travel to fight the Patriots before being captured then rescued my best guess would be around 2012 was when Raiden became a Cyborg

However i should note this is a rough guess as i'm taking into account

- a few months (one or two) of Raiden and Rose seeing each other
- 9 months of Rose's Pregnancy and Raiden led to believe she had a
  miscarriage, i don't think this would be believed unless they made
  him think she miscarriage at during childbirth
- a month of Raiden going off the rails due to his childhood then leaving Rose
- a month for him to find EVA then rescue Sunny from Area 51
- several months working with EVA and the Lost Paradise Army before being captured and experimented on

Comment: Okey, but this is shown in some cutscene or is just "mentioned"?

Comment: @astinx i've only played the first release of MGS4 and they make mention to it in cutscenes and Code Calls however there was a re-release of MGS4 which i haven't bothered to get so i've no idea if they've added any more scenes